# Blender is locking the texture file

Tags: packing

After editing the existing texture in Photoshop cant save over it its is locked by blender, Found that by LockHUnter app.  Texture was Packed in in to the bledner file maybe thats what causing it being locked.  Any ideas ?

Comment: You can unpack the textures from File > External Data > Unpack Resources, but be warned that it will unpack **all** the textures if you have more than one.

Comment: it's not even packed anymore, but it is still locking the texture.  That WAS packed when I got that file

Comment: It should certainly be editable in an external app. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpmVV560nJI) tutorial shows how to edit in Blender using an external editor.

Comment: So no one else experienced this problem? After you get packed scene with all the textures in, after you UNPAck, Photoshop gives an error it I try to edit the files that where packed; to be more specific, when I try to save them.